# Is it possible to attach an anonymous function to two different elements/events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I'm wondering if it is possible to attach an anonymous function to two different elements and two different events using `.on()`. For example, I am using bootstrap tabs and bootstrap raises a custom event type for changing tabs named `shown.bs.tab`. I want to attach an anonymous function to this event using `.on()` but I want to attach the same anonymous function to the `click` event of a button.

I was thinking of doing this:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"],#myButton').on('shown.bs.tab click', function () {
    alert("Tada");
});
```

But this has a side-effect of showing the alert twice for switching tabs. Once for the `shown.bs.tab` event and another time for the `click` event.

I guess I could do this:

```
function ShowAlert() {
    alert("Tada");
}
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', ShowAlert);
$('#myButton').on('click', ShowAlert);
```

But I would like to use an anonymous function. Is there an elegant way to do something like the following?

```
// Pseudocode
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab') AND $('#myButton').on('click') DO: function () {
    alert("Anonymous function called");
});
```

Comment: Why is it important that it's an anonymous function? It's still going to get called _twice_.

Comment: @Halcyon I was just curious if it is possible. Or to make the code more consise. Maybe there is some approach I didn't know about. I thought there would be a way to pass the function directly to `.on()`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do this:

```
var ShowAlert = function() {
    alert("Tada");
}
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', ShowAlert);
$('#myButton').on('click', ShowAlert);
```

`ShowAlert` is technically an anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery uses css selectors, so like you can use same code for different classes you can search more than one object using:

```
var ShowAlert = function() {
        alert("Tada");
    };
    $('.a[data-toggle="tab"],#myButton').on('click', ShowAlert);
```

or

```
var ShowAlert = function() {
    alert("Tada");
};
$('.a[data-toggle="tab"]').add('#myButton').on('click', ShowAlert);
```